# ASP.NET Core MVC - Model properties passed to view showing null in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm passing a view-model to a partial view and by stepping through the code I can tell that the expected data is there:

e.g. the `BatteryLevelTooltip` property

[image: correct-data]

However, stepping over this, the `BatteryLevelTooltip` then becomes null and data isn't rendered in the view:

[image]

I cannot, for the life of me work out why. I'm passing other data in the same way and that's being rendered fine further down the view.

Comment: Please provide your BatteryModel class code

Comment: @Alexander I've just posted my answer as you commented. But you were correct, it was in the class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that for some reason I was setting this property in the getter of another property. This was causing it to return null when it was accessed directly.